# Tikz bar chart, nodes near coords, remove value from a specific bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am using `pgfplots` to display a stacked bar chart. For each x-value, two bars are stacked. I need to show the y-value inside each bar and their sum on top.

I managed to achieve this, however, the first bar is too short to correctly display the inside value. **For the first bar only**, I would like to show only the sum on top while hiding the values inside.

I have no idea how to make such an exception for the first bar only.

[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ECtE.png)

This is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        selective show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \ifnum\coordindex=#1
                   \node[
                   at={(normalized axis cs:%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                   },
                   anchor=south,
                   ]
                   {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                \fi
            },
        },selective show sum on top/.default=0
    }
    \begin{axis}[%
                ybar stacked,
                ymin=0,
                bar width=24pt,
                xtick=data,
                nodes near coords,
                ylabel=Run time (s),
                xlabel=$T$,
                major x tick style = transparent,
                enlarge x limits=0.15,
                legend cell align={left},
                legend style={
                    at={(0.02,0.885)},
                    anchor=west,
                    column sep=1ex
                }
            ]
        \addplot [fill=blue!60] coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,150)
            (2,300)
            (3,450)
        };
        \addplot [fill=red!60,selective show sum on top/.list={0,1,2,3}] coordinates {
            (0,1)
            (1,75)
            (2,150)
            (3,225)
        };
        \legend{Computation,Communication}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please consider extending your code snippet to a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `coordinate style/.condition={x==0}{transparent}` to the `axis` options which would render the labels for the first bar invisible (but they will be still selectable in the PDF).

Alternatively, you could define a custom function that only prints the `nodes at coords` if the `\coordindex` is not `0`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        selective show sum on top/.style={
            /pgfplots/scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                \ifnum\coordindex=#1
                   \node[
                   at={(normalized axis cs:%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x},%
                       \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y})%
                   },
                   anchor=south,
                   ]
                   {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}};
                \fi
            },
        },
        selective show sum on top/.default=0
    }
    \begin{axis}[%
                ybar stacked,
                ymin=0,
                bar width=24pt,
                xtick=data,
                nodes near coords={
                    \ifnum\coordindex=0\else
                        \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta
                    \fi
                },
                ylabel=Run time (s),
                xlabel=$T$,
                major x tick style=transparent,
                enlarge x limits=0.15,
                legend cell align={left},
                legend style={
                    at={(0.02,0.885)},
                    anchor=west,
                    column sep=1ex
                },
            ]
        \addplot [fill=blue!60] coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,150)
            (2,300)
            (3,450)
        };
        \addplot [fill=red!60, selective show sum on top/.list={0,1,2,3}] coordinates {
            (0,1)
            (1,75)
            (2,150)
            (3,225)
        };
        \legend{Computation, Communication}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, it worked like a charm!